# How to select rows of specific names?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a large record of data, around 4,000 rows. The first column has unique names.

I am looking to filter out most of the rows except about 20 names that i am interest in comparing. I have no idea how to do this, its pretty impossible to go through the list manually, but there must be a way to filter out all the other rows so i can do some data comparisons surely?

What's the best approach to do it?

Comment: Have you tried the autofilter functions built into excel? Just highlight the rows and select filter, then select the ones you want to view. There are many formula or VBA approaches as in the answer below, but it depends on how you want to approach it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to use the vlookup function on an used area of the data worksheet or on a different worksheet. As an example: Assume there are 10 columns associated with each row in your table. In a blank area of your worksheet find an area that has 11 blank columns and 20 rows. Assume that the worksheet data starts at Row 1, Column A and the last entry in the table is row 4000 column J.  Assume the first blank row is 5000 and the first column is A.  In   column A starting at row 5000, enter the 20 names you want to filter on. In Row 5000 Column B (R5000CB) enter the formula:
=Vlookup($A5000,$A$1:$M$4000,1)
This formula searches your data table A1:M4000 for the name in column A and puts the result in position B5000. This will be the name you are looking for
Next in R5000:Column C repeat the formula but change the final number in the formula from 1 to 2
=Vlookup($A5000,$A$1:$M$4000,2)
This will search your table for the name in Column A Row 5000 but this time it will put the result from column B in your table into Column C Row 5000.
In Column D repeat the formula and change the last number in the  formula to 3
=Vlookup($A5000,$A$1:$M$4000,3)

Repeat this procedure for each column you want to search.

After the formulas are entered into all of the columns in Row 5000, Highlight all of the formulas and copy then into rows 5001 through 5020 and you will have the data you want to filter on.

Notes:
This solution will work regardless of how many columns are in your table.

The Dollar Signs in the formulas are extremely important. If omitted or extras are inserted, you will not get the desired results.

You can customize your filter by entering only the number of columns you want to compare. If each row in your table has 30 columns and you are only interested in the data in 5 of columns you need to only have the formulas entered in the second through 6 columns in your blank area and change the last number in each formula to match the relative column in your data table.